# Calculate time delta from last occurrence of some boolean column (from last 1) per category?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a simple dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['x','x','x','x','x','y','y','y','y'],
          'Flag': [0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0],
          'time': [10,34,40,43,44,12,20, 46, 51]})
```

I want to calculate the timedelta from the last flag == 1 for each user.
I did the diffs:

```
df.sort_values(['user', 'time']).groupby('user')['time'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(10000000)).dt.total_seconds()/60
```

But it doesn't seem to solve my issue, I need time delta between the 1's and if there wasn't any then fill with some number N.

Please advise

For example:

```
    user Flag   time    diff
0   x    0      10      NaN
1   x    1      34      NaN
2   x    0      40      6.0
3   x    0      43      9.0
4   x    1      44      10.0
5   y    0      12      NaN
6   y    1      20      NaN
7   y    0      46      26.0
8   y    0      51      31.0
```

Comment: What does does not work mean? did you mean because the time column is a string? can you try `df['time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time'].add(":00"))` and then try your code?

Comment: Hi dear @anky, no, I want to diff only between the 1's per group (user). How can I do this and fill everything outside with say 1000000 minutes.

Comment: @anky please have a look on my updated question and what I want the output to be

Comment: @anky IIUC OP wants the diff from last 1 per group if 0, else diff from previous value if 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that I understood correctly, but if you want to compute the time delta only between 1's per group of user, you can apply your computation on the sliced dataframe for 1's only and using `groupby`:

```
df['delta'] = (df[df['Flag'].eq(1)]     # select 1's only
                 .groupby('user')       # group by user
                 ['time'].diff()        # compute the diff
                 .dt.total_seconds()/60 # convert to minutes
               )
```

output:

```
  user  Flag            time  delta
0    x     0 0 days 10:30:00    NaN
1    x     1 0 days 11:34:00    NaN
2    x     0 0 days 11:43:00    NaN
3    y     0 0 days 13:43:00    NaN
4    y     1 0 days 14:40:00    NaN
5    y     0 0 days 15:32:00    NaN
6    y     1 0 days 18:30:00  230.0
7    w     0 0 days 19:30:00    NaN
8    w     0 0 days 20:11:00    NaN
```

##### edit. Here is a working solution for the updated question.

IIUC the update, you want to calculate the difference to the last 1 per user, and if the flag is 1, the difference to the last valid value per user if any.

In summary, it creates subgroup for ranges starting with 1s, then uses these groups to calculate the diffs. Finally masks the 1s with a diff with them previous value (is existing)

```
(df.assign(mask=df['Flag'].eq(1),
           group=lambda d: d.groupby('user')['mask'].cumsum(),
           # diff from last 1
           diff=lambda d: d.groupby(['user', 'group'])['time'].apply(lambda g: g -(g.iloc[0] if g.name[1]>0 else float('nan'))),
           )
   # mask 1s with their own diff
   .assign(## diff=lambda d: d['diff'].mask(d['mask'],d.groupby('user')['time'].diff())  ## OLD VERSION
           diff= lambda d: d['diff'].mask(d['mask'],
                                          (d[d['mask'].groupby(d['user']).cumsum().eq(0)|d['mask']]
                                             .groupby('user')['time'].diff())
                                         )
          )
   .drop(['mask', 'group'], axis=1) # cleanup temp columns
)
```

Output:

```
  user  Flag  time  diff
0    x     0    10   NaN
1    x     1    34  24.0
2    x     0    40   6.0
3    x     0    43   9.0
4    x     1    44  10.0
5    y     0    12   NaN
6    y     1    20   8.0
7    y     0    46  26.0
8    y     0    51  31.0
```

Comment: 1 means a fraud, I want the time from last fraud per user

Comment: @SteveS isn't it what I have done? For user x there was a single fraud, for y two and the second occurred 230 minutes after the first one.

Comment: Nope, for user ```y``` you have 4 entries first one should remain NaN, second also, third should be around 50 minutes, forth around 3 hours.

Comment: Please have a look on my updated question @mozway

Comment: @SteveS updated answer

Comment: Hey @mozway, please look at your 4th row ```[x, 1, 44, 1.0]```, it's wrong, it should not be 1.0 diff but 10 (44 - 34 because the last fraud was on index row 1. 
In the future when x will do another transaction we will again calculate the diff from index row 4. Other than that it's a working solution.

Comment: @SteveS `1` is what you have in the expected output of your question.

Comment: Please see updated question, @mozway sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: Dear @mozway, can you please advise what should I change to make it 10?

Comment: Thanks dear @mozway, if you could explain the answer it would be great. Should it be that complicated to do this calculation?

Comment: What is the output of ```g.name[1]```? @mozway

Comment: `g.name[1]` will be the custom indexer assigned before. It will be 0 if there was never a fraud

Comment: Thanks @mozway, but in my case the time is a python timestamp and if I am doing the ```g -(g.iloc[0] if g.name[1]>0 else float('nan'))``` part, it returns with an error:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'DatetimeArray' and 'float'

Comment: try to replace `float('nan')` with `pd.NaT`

Comment: Thanks dear @mozway, and regarding the ```diff= lambda d:``` expressions, it means for every row of df? What is the d here? Our whole df?

Comment: d is the whole dataframe in this context. It is the same as doing `df['diff'] = …`

Comment: Dear @mozway, just one last thing, if you don't mind, regarding index rows 1 and 6, what should I change to make them NaN also? Because the if we start with 0's there wasn't any fraud so it should be NaN. I have updated the question, sorry again, please advise.

Comment: @SteveS questions are made to help you solve a problem, not for me to develop your whole application ;) You can use a mask on the value of Flag and the fact that a cumsum on the mask would be 1 (first value).